# How to make shipping cost variable based on the shipping address in stripe in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, payment, payment-processing

I am using Stripe's Checkout API. I'd like to offer international shipping, with different shipping options and a shipping cost based on the country dinamically choosed on the checkout stripe page. Is there a way, using Checkout, to make shipping cost options conditional on the shipping address country the user inputs in the Checkout form?  This is an excerpt from my code:

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    success_url: "http://localhost:4242/success.html?id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
    cancel_url: "http://localhost:4242/cancel.html",
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    mode: "payment",
    line_items: [
      {
        price: "price_1Nxx6ZDsK4pxN0rvXLjRy7bJ",
        quantity: req.body.quantity,
      },
    ],
    customer: "cus_Ol9Y0V0GCXTmSF",
    billing_address_collection: "required",
    shipping_address_collection: {
      allowed_countries: [
        "AT",
        "BE",
        "BG",
        "HR",
        "CY",
        "CZ",
        "DK",
        "EE",
        "FI",
        "FR",
        "DE",
        "GR",
        "HU",
        "IE",
        "IT",
        "LV",
        "LT",
        "LU",
        "MT",
        "NL",
        "PL",
        "PT",
        "RO",
        "SK",
        "SI",
        "ES",
        "SE",
      ],
    },
shipping_options: [
    {
      shipping_rate_data: {
        type: 'fixed_amount',
        fixed_amount: {
          amount: 0,
          currency: 'eur',
        },
        display_name: 'Free shipping',
        delivery_estimate: {
          minimum: {
            unit: 'business_day',
            value: 5,
          },
          maximum: {
            unit: 'business_day',
            value: 7,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      shipping_rate_data: {
        type: 'fixed_amount',
        fixed_amount: {
          amount: 1000,
          currency: 'usd',
        },
        display_name: 'Express',
        delivery_estimate: {
          minimum: {
            unit: 'business_day',
            value: 1,
          },
          maximum: {
            unit: 'business_day',
            value: 5,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
    customer_update: { shipping: "auto" },
    automatic_tax: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    allow_promotion_codes: true,

  
  });
```

Imagine this scenario, pre products are in Italy, if the user insert an italian shipping address it's alright otherwise I want change shipping cost, for instance for France I would have 10 euro low service and 20 euro fast service.
How could I implement this in stripe?

Comment: check this document
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/during-payment/charge-shipping

Comment: Basically I should pick up shipping information upfront, I have to manually calculate ship costs based on the inserted address, and in a second step pay. This make the implementation complicated.  Instead is there a method that allow me to listen (webhook?) the inserted address in the checkout stripe page, manually calculate ship costs and in some way modify the field value of shipping cost in the form in the checkout stripe page?

Answer (score 2):

It's a good idea... Not possible though.

The only such thing is Stripe Tax, where the tax-rate is computed based on the address entered on Session - only for Tax purposes though, you couldn't even use it as a hack for Shipping rates, since it calculates tax based on your registrations.

The only option you have is to collect address before the Session, not collect it on the Session, and pass a shipping_rate that is appropriate to the address you collected.

Comment: indeed I already calculate tax based on the address, it works perfectly. It's a shame that isn't possible the same for shipping cost. Thanks anyway